# Pull Gmails into a Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This script works brilliantly to pull emails into my sheet. My problem is that the function only pulls the first two fields listed. e.g., getPlainBody, getSubject - even though more fields are asked for. So instead of having one function that pulls all the fields I need (getPlainBody, getSubject, getTo, getDate, getFrom) I only get the first two (getPlainBody, getSubject). Is there an obvious modification that will pull all 5 fields into the sheet?

```
function getEmails_(q) {
  sh0.clear();
    var emails = [];
    var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
    for (var i in threads) {
        var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j in msgs) {
            emails.push([msgs[j].getPlainBody(), [msgs[j].getSubject(), [msgs[j].getDate(), [msgs[j].getTo(), [msgs[j].getFrom()

            ]]]]]);
        }
    }
    return emails;

}

function appendData_(sh0, array2d) {
    sh0.getRange(sh0.getLastRow() + 1, 1, array2d.length, array2d[0].length).setValues(array2d);
}

function saveEmails() {
    var array2d = getEmails_(SEARCH_QUERY);
    if (array2d) {
        appendData_(sh0, array2d);
    }}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fine the problem is how you are constructing the 2D array.

in the `.push()` method, your use of the square brackets - [] - is building an array within an array within another array within another array within another array within another array, it's easier to see it in the screenshot below.
[image]

What you need is 1 array of horizontals cells with an array of vertical rows.[image]

So change:

```
emails.push([msgs[j].getPlainBody(), [msgs[j].getSubject(), [msgs[j].getDate(), [msgs[j].getTo(), [msgs[j].getFrom()]]]]]);
```

to

```
emails.push([msgs[j].getPlainBody(), msgs[j].getSubject(), msgs[j].getDate(), msgs[j].getTo(), msgs[j].getFrom()]);
```

On a personal note, I usually always format the date to something a little more readable. You can use `Utilities` to do this. Ex:  format: `Thu Jun 15 2017 11:18:18 GMT+0700 (ICT)` to `15/06/2017 @ 11:18`

```
var formatDate = Utilities.formatDate(emails[i][2], 'GMT+07:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy @ HH:mm')
```

Comment: James - Thank you so very much! Your fix works and I will definitely work with your date suggestion. - josh

Comment: @JoshuaRoberts Please consider accepting my answer.